# Need help seperating column names in imported csv file without manually doing it in excel

Tags: r, csv, tibble

Last column of csv file is being discarded because there is no column name.

```
#import data from barttorvik 
url <- "http://barttorvik.com/2021_team_results.csv"
data <- read_csv(url)
```

I get the following warning

```
warning: 347 parsing failures.
row col   expected     actual                                          file
  1  -- 44 columns 45 columns 'http://barttorvik.com/2021_team_results.csv'
  2  -- 44 columns 45 columns 'http://barttorvik.com/2021_team_results.csv'
  3  -- 44 columns 45 columns 'http://barttorvik.com/2021_team_results.csv'
  4  -- 44 columns 45 columns 'http://barttorvik.com/2021_team_results.csv'
  5  -- 44 columns 45 columns 'http://barttorvik.com/2021_team_results.csv'
```

The column name "Fun RK" and "adjt" are not separated in the csv file so the last column name is "Fun RK, adjt" and the column only contains Fun RK data. Need a quick fix without manually downloading csv file into excel and changing the column names every time I need to update the data.

Comment: Hi Brian!  It would help if you'd post a reprex (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), which in this case would include the first three or four lines of your text file.  That way other folks can test any coding suggestions before posting them!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

data.table's `fread` reads this accurately :

```
url <- "http://barttorvik.com/2021_team_results.csv"
data <- data.table::fread(url, quote = '')
```

You may want to clean up the column names though because quotes are present in the last 2 column names.

```
colnames(data) <- gsub('"', '', names(data))
```

Comment: This is perfect.